# How to remove settings? or any direct access to Settings table?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How can we remove a tenant or user setting that has been saved to the database? so that the default Host setting is used again?

I don't see any direct access to the settings table via a repository? nor do I see an DeleteSetting options within the SettingManager.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

take care,
jasen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the setting to the default value removes it from the database.

```cs
var settingName = "mySettingName";
var userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(1, 2);

var defaultValue = _settingDefinitionManager.GetSettingDefinition(settingName).DefaultValue;
_settingManager.ChangeSettingForUserAsync(userIdentifier, settingName, defaultValue);
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron!  Is that documented somewhere that I missed? I feel like I scour the docs for answers to these kinds of things, and come up empty a bit too often.

Comment: The classes and methods are mentioned in the documentation on [Setting Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management#isettingdefinitionmanager). The behaviour when it is changed to the default value is implementation-dependent and can be found in the source code of [SettingManager](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/c7e3be16974b3520361178aa61c139a059284288/src/Abp/Configuration/SettingManager.cs#L322-L331), since ABP is open source.

Comment: I appreciate your help Aaron.  Abp is an awesome tool, albeit lacking a lot of documenation still.  This is a good example.  In no way would I ever consider looking at the source code for UpdateOrInsert for how to remove an item.  Anyway, keep up the great work!